# Trim string before numbers (0-9) in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to remove all the letters before numbers in the below strings:

```
BIO105L
BIO106
BIO106L
BIO201
```

I want the letters after the number to stay and not trimmed.

I tried to do this:

```
select right(s.EVENT_ID, len(s.EVENTID) - charindex('%[^0-9]%', s.EVENT_ID))
from EVENTS s
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Do **all** of your course codes use three-character prefixes? What kind of database is this (different dialects have subtly different substring functions)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely looking for [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql) as you are searching for a pattern:

```
SELECT RIGHT(s.EVENT_ID, LEN(s.EVENT_ID) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', s.EVENT_ID) + 1) FROM EVENTS s
```